# Custom Rss Feed In Magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to create Rss Feed for my blog. I am using extension for blog.

How can I achieve this in magento2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello imtiaz,**

1. Login to admin panel
2. Go to Stores > Configuration
3. Under Catalog, select RSS Feed
4. Expand RSS Config and enable RSS.

[image]

5. Expand Wishlist and enable RSS

[image]

6. Expand Catalog and enable RSS Feed for:

New Products – Notify when a new product is added to the catalog.
Special Products – Notify for a product with a special price.
Coupons/Discounts – Notify when discounts are offered.
Top Level Category -Notify of any difference in the top-level category structure of your catalog, which is displayed in the main menu.

[image]

7. Expand Order and enable Customer Order Status Notification

[image]

8. Save the configuration.

That was all about configuring the RSS feed in Magento 2.

You may check the frontend with “/rss” at the end of the page URL

[image]

**Hope, this will help you out, Thanks**